EF Core optional 1 to 1 relationship
I've got a situation where I need to do an optional 1 to 1 relationship in EF Core.
I've simplified what I need using books example (hopefully context still makes sense).
The context is I have a feed, that feed has books sold by suppliers and the price they want to sell it at. We are a reseller, a customer might choose a book from a supplier and buy it directly from them. But we want a way to override the price of the book for all suppliers.
public class SupplierBook
{
    public int SupplierBookId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BookOverride")]
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public int BookSupplierId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public virtual BookOverride? BookOverride { get; set; }
}

public class BookOverride
{
    [Key]
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceOverride { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BookId")]
    public SupplierBook SupplierBook { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public void DoTest()
    {
        var bookFromSup1 = new SupplierBook() { SupplierBookId = 0,  BookId = 10, BookSupplierId = 1, Price = 10.50M };
        var bookFromSup2 = new SupplierBook() { SupplierBookId = 1, BookId = 10, BookSupplierId = 2, Price = 90.50M };
        var bookFromSup3 = new SupplierBook() { SupplierBookId = 2, BookId = 11, BookSupplierId = 2, Price = 5.50M };

        var priceOverride = new BookOverride() { BookId = 10, PriceOverride = 15.0M };

        var context = new BookDBContext();

        context.SupplierBooks.Add(bookFromSup1);
        context.SupplierBooks.Add(bookFromSup2);
        context.SupplierBooks.Add(bookFromSup3);

        context.BookOverrides.Add(priceOverride);

        context.SaveChanges();

        var bookWithOveride = context.SupplierBooks
            .Where(o => o.BookId == 10 && o.BookSupplierId == 2)
            .Include(o => o.BookOverride).First();

        Debug.WriteLine(bookWithOveride.BookOverride.PriceOverride); // prints 15.00

        var bookWithNoOveride = context.SupplierBooks
          .Where(o => o.BookId == 11 && o.BookSupplierId == 2)
          .Include(o => o.BookOverride).First();

        Debug.WriteLine(bookWithNoOveride.BookOverride == null); // prints true
    }
}

Using the current approach when inserting the SupplierBook data I get the following error:

foreign key constraint fails (......., CONSTRAINT ... FOREIGN KEY (...) REFERENCES ... (...) ON DELETE CASCADE)

Edit for clarity:
Think of BookID as an ISBN number. Each supplier has the same book at different prices. What we want to override is ALL books with the ISBN number to have a specific price, not just the book from that supplier. Also if there are no books in the SupplierBook table with that ISBN number, we still want to keep the BookOverride row, as that book might appear again in the feed, and we want to use the override price previously set.
There is no "Book" table, as there are no common fields, each supplier might name the book slightly different, so the "book name" for example, would also be in the SupplierBook table.

we still want to keep the BookOverride row -- That means that BookOverride must have its own reference to supplier. Just BookId can't be its only key property. You should be able to have a database with only BookOverride data, to which you can add SupplierBooks later.

You need to make the foreign key on your SupplierBook
[ForeignKey("BookOverride")]
public int BookId { get; set; }

nullable as well - public int? BookId { get; set; } since this is the side of the relationship that has the 'not-required' semantics.
But the way you've set up your models means that you're basically adding a bookOverride every time you're instantiating your supplierBook with a BookID value which is probably not what you're after. You should remove the [ForeignKey("BookId")] from your BookOverride model to set up the relationship correctly.
You can read more here MS Docs

hey thanks,  I tried as you suggested, but still can't add the data, still complaining about  Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails . This is with SupplierBook  int? BookId and removing the navigation property from BookOverride

Generally it should be okay like that, but perhaps the SQL DDL is already wrongly generated and your constraint is not nullable in the actual database. Can you check the actual database model foreign key?

Also, another thing :) If you're keeping the ForeingKey in the SupplierBook (which is fine) and instantiating the SupplierBook with BookID (foreign key pointing to BookOverride), you need to first insert the BookOverride with the respective BookID - 10 in your case.

Thanks again, I think that is the main issue, and thing I want to avoid , I want to only grab the overrides if it exists, instead of having a copy of ever book in override with blank details. Does that make sense? If I was to keep a record for every book id in override it seems to work, but trying to have it so it only grabs the record if its there, if not its null

Sure, that will work. Just don't initially pass the BookID (foreign key reference) in the SupplierBook and use the navigational property in BookOverride to describe the foreign key. BookOverride always has a SupplierBook, SupplierBook won't need the ForeignKey attribute and foreign key anymore, the navigational property can stay in there. And after that you can just instantiate your SupplierBooks without a "BookID" foreign key at first. When you create your BookOverride then the respective SupplierBook's navigational property should reference your BookOverride.

Making some assumptions here:

There’s a Book entity
There’s a BookSupplier entity
SupplierBook relates a BookSupplier to a book
BookOverride overrides a price for a supplier book

First let’s change the name of BookOverride to SupplierBookOverride as this better describes its purpose.  Then the shared PK property should not be BookId as it’s not overriding a Book’s value(s) but the SupplierBook’s value(s), so let’s rename that property to SupplierBookId.
Now you may see your error: you are using BookId values as the FK to SupplierBook when you need to use SupplierBook.SupplierBookId values.  The appropriate values in your test data are 0,1,2 but you use 10 which doesn’t exist, hence the FK violation.
Finally, remove the “BookOverride” foreign key attribute from SupplierBook.BookId as this property should reference the Book entity, not the override entity.  The principle entity of a 1:1 relationship does not have a foreign key; the shared primary key in the dependent entity is all that’s needed.

Thanks for the response, I made an edit for more clarity
